# request access token API key

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm using API key and API secret to authenticate but I don't know which endpoint and body to use and to get the access token , I want just to perform actions on my own account so I'm not using the oAuth2.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

The documentation: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#api-client-libraries points to usng a 3rd party lib to make life easier. Have you tried this or is it relevant?